# Adding an Identity and Access Management (IAM) role to get around the error "You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is adding an Identity and Access Management (IAM) role to get around the error
"You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy" secure? Is the solution outlined on this site secure? https://www.dailytask.co/task/aws-s3-bucket-policy-access-denied-even-with-admin-permission-ahmed-zidan

I kept running into the error *"You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy"* when trying to edit bucket policies for static website files hosts in an S3 Bucket, as well as upload new copies of files.

Static website hosting is enabled and my current permissions for the bucket are:

[image]

and my current bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found a solution at https://www.dailytask.co/task/aws-s3-bucket-policy-access-denied-even-with-admin-permission-ahmed-zidan But I want to determine if it is a secure method to be able to edit bucket policies and upload files.

Basically, the solution according to the dailytask site is for the user to create a new policy with the following rules:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "ModifyBucketPolicy",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
              "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "AccessS3Console",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetBucketLocation",
              "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      }
  ]
}
```

and then add the policy to the user. I can now upload new files without errors and edit bucket policies.

But are there possible security issues with this? Security from public web users?

Or from other AWS users logged into the account? I'm the sole user of the AWS account.

Should I delete the overall "fix" from the website and add appropriate permissions in the bucket policy for each S3 bucket?

What's an example of a bucket policy that would let me upload files without errors when using the public access rules in the image?

Comment: `arn:aws:s3:::*` allows for changing policy on every single bucket of yours. It should be limited to one specific bucket that your user can modify.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that now. I'm the sole user of the AWS account, so that's reasonably safe.

Comment: If so, then what are you worrying about with security?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to be sure there isn't a security issue :) Is there a  bucket policy I can use for each bucket that would allow uploads for that bucket?

Comment: Anonymous uploads to buckets are very dangerous. You may end up with unwanted and/or illegal content. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: No, I don't want anonymous uploads; I only want to upload as myself. Does the dailytask bucket policy above allow anonymous uploads from any website viewer?

Comment: No it does not. Only you will be able to upload objects. But anyone will be able to download them due to your bucket policy.

Comment: Yes, it's bucket for static webhosting.